# Angular JS - Optimal way to change one scope's state and set the rest to false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have 4 fields in my view that I want to either open/close when clicking, while also closing the other three.

```
<div class="square red"></div>
<div class="square blue"></div>
<div class="square yellow"></div>
<div class="square green"></div>
```

In order to achieve that, what I did is adding an `ng-class` that is triggered whenever a `ng-click` is done in that field. So the view would be something like this:

```
<div class="square red" ng-class="{'open':redSquare == true}" ng-click="clickRedSquare()"></div>
<div class="square blue" ng-class="{'open':blueSquare == true}" ng-click="clickBlueSquare()"></div>
<div class="square yellow" ng-class="{'open':yellowSquare == true}" ng-click="clickYellowSquare()"></div>
<div class="square green" ng-class="{'open':greenSquare == true}" ng-click="clickGreenSquare()"></div>
```

And In my controller I would have something like this:

```
$scope.redSquare = true;
$scope.clickRedSquare = function() {
    $scope.redSquare = !$scope.redSquare;
    $scope.blueSquare = false;
    $scope.greenSquare = false;
    $scope.yellowSquare = false;
};
$scope.clickBlueSquare = function() {
    $scope.redSquare = false;
    $scope.blueSquare = !$scope.blueSquare;
    $scope.greenSquare = false;
    $scope.yellowSquare = false;
};
$scope.clickGreenSquare = function() {
    $scope.redSquare = false;
    $scope.blueSquare = false;
    $scope.greenSquare = !$scope.greenSquare;
    $scope.yellowSquare = false;
};
$scope.clickYellowSquare = function() {
    $scope.redSquare = false;
    $scope.blueSquare = false;
    $scope.greenSquare = false;
    $scope.yellowSquare = !$scope.yellowSquare;
};
```

I would like to ask what would be the most optimal way in Angular (if any) in order not to have duplicate code. You can see the working plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OGqghOl1D7JwkVp5f8rQ?p=preview). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep separate variables for each square, you could do something like:

```
$scope.clickSquare = function(name) {
    ["redSquare",
     "blueSquare",
     "greenSquare",
     "yellowSquare"].forEach(function(e) {
        $scope[e] = (e === name) ? !$scope[e] : false;
     });
}
```

And then just call this method with an argument `ng-click="clickSquare('redSquare')"`

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HtOcbjpkTCtYbmV4jDLh?p=preview)